# Compatible hector version for apache cassandra 1.2.5

Tags: cassandra

Which is the compatible Hector version to connect to cassandra? I have apache cassandra 1.2.5

**Is it Core 0.8.0-2 / 1.0-1 or
Test 1.0-1 or
HOM 1.1-02/2.0-01/3.0-01**

Which one I need to use if it is apache-cassandra 1.2.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want the latest **core** version (to get the very latest clone the [git repository](https://github.com/hector-client/hector) and build it using maven, or the much simpler option, use [hector's maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.prettyprint/hector-core) and add the dependency *which can be found below*). The test version is unit tests, but building the whole git repository and including the tests along side the core driver shouldn't be a problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
    <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-5</version>
</dependency>
```

So from the dependency you can see the latest version is **1.0-5**. For latest Cassandra pick the latest driver, if that fails get their last known 'production ready' version which in this case would appear to be 1.0-5.

But on a side note, pick a better driver, Hector is known for being difficult to work with and datastax advise use of [cql drivers](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) for new Cassandra applications.